# Jquery Dropdown on change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this code below should capture the selected value and add it to a div. I can't for the life of me get the code to respond. I've tried different selectors and event listeners but still doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$("#mapDataTable select").on("change", function(){
var option = $(this).val();
$("#exBuilder").innerHTML += ' '+option;
});

$("#mapDataColumn select").on("change", function(){
var option = $(this).val();
$("#exBuilder").innerHTML += ' '+option;
});

$("#analyzeFunction").on("change", function(){
var option = $(this).val();
$("#exBuilder").innerHTML += ' '+option;
});

$("#parameterValue select").on("change", function(){
var option = $(this).val();
$("#exBuilder").innerHTML += ' '+option;
});
```

Map to  DataTable
                                t_

```
                    <div id="mapDataColumn" name="mapDataColumn" style="width: calc(25% - 4px)"  class='inlineBlock hundredHeight'>
                        <select id="">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Map to Data Column</option>
                            <option value="c_">c_</option>
                        </select>                   
                    </div><!--mapDataColumn-->
                    <div id="analyzeFunction" name="analyzeFunction" style="width: calc(25% - 4px)"  class="inlineBlock hundredHeight">
                        <select id="">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Analyze Function</option>
                            <option value="add">Add +</option>
                            <option value="subtract">Subtract -</option>
                            <option value="multiple">Multiply *</option>
                            <option value="divide">Divide /</option>
                            <option value="greater">Greater ></option>
                            <option value="less">Less <</option>
                            <option value="greatequal">Greater | Equal</option>
                            <option value="lessequal">Less | Equal</option>
                            <option value="equal">Equal =</option>
                            <option value="notequal">Not Equal <></option>
                            <option value="and">And &</option>
                            <option value="or">Or |</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><!--analyzeFunction-->
                    <div id="parameterValue" name="parameterValue" style="width: calc(25% - 4px)"  class="inlineBlock hundredHeight">
                        <select id="">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Display Parameter Value</option>
                            <option value="amount">Amount</option>
                            <option value="sum">Sum</option>
                            <option value="average">Average</option>
                            <option value="count">Count</option>
                            <option value="percentage">Percentage</option>
                            <option value="min">Minimum</option>
                            <option value="max">Maximum</option>
                            <option value="median">Median</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><!--parameterValue-->
```

Comment: Is js code wrapped on document ready function, or added before closing body tag?

Comment: Code is wrapped in on ready

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: Works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/53dfgf54/

Comment: Strange my fiddle doesnt work:

https://jsfiddle.net/aadu8jou/

Comment: You should add jquery lib in your fiddle

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53dfgf54/1/)

Comment: innerHTML is a javascript property, not jquery. You need to either use $("#exBuilder")[0].innerHTML or $("#exBuilder").html()

Comment: Okay I have changed the js code and while it now works in my fiddle it doesnt on my localhost - I cant even get an alert out!

Comment: Here's the working version : https://jsfiddle.net/aadu8jou/3/

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, turns out the code was outside the damn on ready brackets. You all helped me to realize thank you very much!